# How to add Layout at run time and mange on the next and previous click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

[image]

**Hello, I stuck in this:**

The whole section is divided into 3 parts as you can see in the image.

"Middle section" is a layout which I want add at run time **(Relative Layout)** and this Relative Layout i need to change the background with some image.

**Where I stuck** :

In short _ _

**Just Like another Adapter (paderAdapter/BaseAdapter/ArrayAdapter) we have pass some value / arrayList from crating it. What if I add those value at run time like click on the next and one another just add and I'll mange all the layout**

Briefly _ _

I want to add another relative layout when I click on next button and same as previous add to background with the image and again click on next "Add another relative layout" and so on.

If I click back button than view will change with the previous relative layout. Just like View Pager.

But I don't need swipe gesture in this, only view change on the next and previous button click.

If this thing is easily handle through ViewPager or something else way is better way to generate this thing.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Why do you want to add Relativelayout onClicking the next button you can just change the contents of the layout instead

Comment: I need to add background on every page and each page add at runtime , may be number of that layout are 5 / 10 / 20 etc that is reason I need to add at run time  @LochanaRagupathy

Comment: In View Pager, I am not getting the way to add number of pages at run time. @BirajZalavadia

Comment: Have you tried coding? can you post some of your code for better help

Comment: I worked on view pager but from the view pager I am not able to do this thing. Like if I need to create custom ListView then we can create a custom row and add into the ArrayAdapter. Just like this I need to add Custom layout but where I add into like ArrayAdapter / pagerAdapter. Does it sense ? @LochanaRagupathy

Answer (score 0):

From your above comments I understand that you have to display a Relative Layout which has a different background when you click next each time. My suggestion would be

1) Add your background drawables or images in an ArrayList or List

2) Set the background image which is at the position 0 initially to your Ralative Layout's ImageView.

3)On clicking next button just set the next position's image into the view apply the vice-verse to the previous

You can also use slide animations to show as the picture moves to next and previous.